# Comparing a pointer to a pointer with a character?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a character array. A pointer points to that character array. Also, another pointer points to that pointer i.e. it is a pointer to a pointer. Now, I need to compare the pointer to the pointer with a character literal, say "a".

I tried strcmp but it didn't work.

How can I do this?

```
    char arr[1000];
    char *ptr,*ptr1,**curr;
    ptr=arr;        //pointer pointer to that array
    curr=&ptr;      //pointer to a pointer
    if(**curr=='.') //doesn't work
        printf("Some code");
```

Comment: Well, apart from you comparing to `'.'` instead of `'a'`, the code you've posted is not the problem.

Comment: What makes you think that your code "doesn't work"?

Comment: Why doesn't work? Code is correct. What is wrong is to use of `strcmp()` to compare chars. `strcmp()` compares 2 `NULL` terminated **strings**, not char literals. Try your code adding intialization to array: `char arr[1000]={'.'};`

Comment: Could it be that you confuse the character literal, which would be 'a' (single quotes) with the string literal "a" (double quotes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you are speaking about the following

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char arr[1000] = "a";
char *ptr = arr;
char **curr = &ptr;

if ( strcmp( *curr, "a" ) == 0 ) puts( "They are equal" );
```

Or

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char arr[1000] = "abcd";
char *ptr = arr;
char **curr = &ptr;
char *ptr2 = "ab";

if ( strncmp( *curr, ptr2, strlen( ptr2 ) ) == 0 ) puts( "They are equal" );
```

If you need to compare a single character then you can write

```
char arr[1000] = "a";
char *ptr = arr;
char **curr = &ptr;

if ( **curr == 'a' ) puts( "They are equal" );
```

or

```
char arr[1000] = "ab";
char *ptr = arr;
char **curr = &ptr;

if ( ( *curr )[1] == 'b' ) puts( "They are equal" );
```

Comment: @ameyCU It was a typo.:)

Comment: Ohh ok ,yes yes  .Cheers !! :)

Comment: If the array contains `'a'` not followed by a null (i.e. initialized as `char arr[1000] = {'a'};`) the `strcmp()` will fail anyway...

Comment: @Frankie_C  But that's not how it is initialized here. Please see above.

Comment: @ameyCU I was talking for a general case, in the question there is no initialization, so we don't know what the array contained.

Comment: @Frankie_C  Well seems I misunderstood. Yes I agree on that.

Comment: @Frankie_C  If you initialized the array like  char arr[1000] = {'a'}; then it is zero-terminated because all other elements of the array will be zero-initialized.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Hi Vlad. Your objection is right, if an initialized array is placed in `.data` section and the compiler should initiallize the remaining part of the array with null equivalent, but on some compilers this not always true. BTW still we can have an uninitialized array where the user just put an `'a'` in the first element leaving the rest uninitialized. In this case coming from `.bss` section we still have problem using `strcmp()`. What I don't understand is why we should use `strcmp()` to compare chars as asked in the question...

Comment: @Frankie_C  I already showed in my post how to compare separate characters or sequences of characters with a given length using strncmp.